# How to put out the fire of an eternal burning artifact on a water limited map?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I had some fun with a dragon, and some artifacts got caught on !!fire!! which produce smoke. I'm aware that artifacts will never get destroyed and that water [should cool them off](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Fire#Artifacts), I've tried using the bucket squad to not avail, it only produced steam. Is there a way to un-burn the eternal burning artifact?

I built a reservoir of water just above with a floor hatch (1x1x1 with 7 units of water), it only evaporated into steam and put more pressure on my limited water sources...

Comment: What do you mean by "water constrained map"? How much water is available? Where is it? I'm afraid extinguishing a fire will include water in some way.

Comment: I think that instead of a reservoir, you flood the room with the artifacts to see if it helps with cooling.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer instead of constrained, I think it's more accurate to use "limited". It's a dense forest with some murky pools.

Comment: @BanhMiDacBiet That would require more water than what it's available (murky pools). I dropped 7 units of water and all of it evaporated.

Answer (score 1):

Fire is hot enough to evaporate some water before it can be extinguished, so the main problem here is getting enough water. There are two ways you can gather water.

You've mentioned murky pools in your embark area. Murky pools will refill when it rains, so if you're not in an arid biome you can dig channels from your pools to an artificial reservoir, block them with floodgates, and empty them into the reservoir after rain pools up in them.

Alternatively, caverns are known to have large underground lakes in them, which will continuously refill if they touch the edge of the map. With a system of pumps or a well and much patience, you can bring this water to the surface, and eventually have enough to extinguish the artifact, or for other needs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add one unit each time. Just dig 4x4 area near the block containing fire. Connect it to reservoir(murky pool). Connect to to fired artifact with a flood gate. (This is important)Block the flood gate.

When the 4x4 reservoir fills completely, open the flood gate.

The excess water will guarantee to extinguish the flame.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Fire#Artifacts), water should extinguish the artifact. Since the source of ignition was dragonfire, the temperature might be very high and will need time to cool down.

Comment: Water can extinguish fire, but fire also causes water to evaporate if there's not enough of it. Also, do you realize you linked something that's in the question and that the OP already tried?

Comment: As missed his link. My guess would then be that the dragonfire just has the temperature of the artifact extremely high so it will take a lot of water.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer is there a way to know the temperature or how much water should be enough? I think that would answer the question.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think the temperature matters at all, all fire should be the same. I don't know how much water is enough.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer This is from the wiki on fire safe items. 

"As far as the game is concerned, only materials which are stable at the temperature 11000 °U (i.e. MELTING_POINT/BOILING_POINT/IGNITE_POINT/HEATDAM_POINT greater than 11000 and COLDDAM_POINT less than 11000) are considered fire-safe. Despite this temperature being considered fire-safe, actual fire can generate temperatures significantly higher (in particular, any burning item will heat up to 200 degrees above its material's ignite point"

So it seems that if the artifact temp is well above its ignite point you just need more water

Comment: Well, I tried 21 units of water without any good result, it's still burning.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue (v50.09).  Bucket brigade did not work.  Pumping water from a river into the room with the burning artifact did not work.  Dropping 7/7 water from a bridge above did not work.

What did work was causing a cave-in, dropping the burning artifact into 7/7 water.